# How to add temporal tables to EF Code-First DBContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, temporal-tables

I want to add SQL temporal tables to my project in DBContext not in migration file? How to achieve it?
Edit:
I've added it to seed function but it's still not working

```
 protected override void Seed(MSDBContext context)
    {
        string sql = @"  ALTER TABLE dbo.Workshops

 ADD SysStartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START  
  CONSTRAINT DF_Workshops_SysStartTime DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME() NOT NULL,
  SysEndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END 
  CONSTRAINT DF_Workshops_SysEndTime DEFAULT CONVERT (DATETIME2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59') NOT NULL,
         PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
  GO

  ALTER TABLE dbo.Workshops
      SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.WorkshopsHistory))
  GO";
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);

        context.SaveChanges();

        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: EF is not made to create temporary tables. "Temporary" has the meaning of "inside one transaction - so inside a query, you create a table, transform it, get some output and delete it. All in the same step. EF does not support this complexity of queries.
Do you just want to create a table at runtime ? That would be something different.

Comment: @holger - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Holger Temporal Tables are not Temporary Tables.

Comment: I didn't know about temporal tables - so thanks for that hint. I doubt that EF Core does support it

Answer (score 1):

Using Entity Framework Core 7, I can achieve this like so:

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Workshop> Workshops { get; set; }

    // ... ctor etc

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Workshop>()
            .ToTable("Workshops", b => b.IsTemporal());
    }
}
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score -1):

You can run adhoc sql queries if you wanted to just create tables.

```
using (var ctx = new DBDataContext())
{
    var rowsEffected = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("YOUR SQL TO ADD TABLES");
}
```

If this doesn't work, you dont have to use EF, you could use good old ADO.NET sql client classes to run queries.

Comment: this is not an answer as OP already told that using ExecuteSqlCommand() does not work

Comment: @DanielSchmid, it might have been before the OP edited their question after trying it?